# How to pass "messages" from qmake to C++?

Tags: c++, qmake

I have a unit test which needs **external data** which is in a file `unit_test_data`. I would like `unit_test_data` to travel together with the source code (also in the version control system). But I do not know how to **make the unit test aware of the location of** `unit_test_data` in the file system. The `qmake` system knows the location, but how can it pass this knowledge to the code?

```
#include <ifstream>

void test()
{
    std::string path = path_to_file + "/unit_test_data";
      // How can I pass this ^ from qmake? 
    std::ifstream(path.c_str());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new macro, in the `.pro` file:

```
DEFINES += FILENAME=\\\"/unit_test_data\\\"
```

As you see the issue is that is has to be quoted twice.

And then, in the C++ code, use the macro expansion:

```
std::string path = path_to_file + FILENAME;
```